# thunderbird authentication fails

Tags: thunderbird

being reasonably new to all this, I struck a problem.  I used to click on the thunderbird icon on the tray and immediately get email (in and out).  Suddenly, it asks for a password.!  I enter the password I saved for it but it fails to authenticate.  I tried downloading and installing a fresh thunderbird over the old one, no go.  I have tried many many things to overcome this but zero sucess. Some of the things I try fail and trying to sort them out has me totally confused.  Should I reformat the computer and reinstall everything from a backup (if it works).  I ask that because I have tried restore several times and nothing works there also.  Time to shout HELP.  Thank you to all who might be in a position to help me out.     Rod.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: What did I originally do.?  Nothing, it just started asking for a password.   What have I done since.?   I have tried to reinstall Thunderbird mail without any success. I.E. Nothing changed, it still wanted a password which it did not recognise.  What do I wish to achieve.?  I would like to get my email working again so that one of the organizations I volunteer with may again receive minutes and other alerts.  At no stage have I received any error message, except for the Authentication failure.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of that password dialogue?

Comment: It asks for **which** password? Where did you *save a password for it*? How did you try to reinstall – and what went wrong? What *many many things* did you try? Sorry, but things like *Some of the things I try fail* don't help at all. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/951826/edit) and provide clear information about what's going wrong, maybe then somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: It asks for the pop3 server password.  I saved a password in an external HDD.  It is still there.   How did I try to reinstall, I downloaded the .tar.bz2 file from the Ubuntu site.  I then googled instructions for installing this type of file, if this isn't clear enough, then I do apologise.  As for pasting the errors received.  This will also need to be googled so I can figure out how to crop the screen shot then paste it (them) to a reply.  At present, it either posts the location of the file, or if I get lucky, it adds the screen shot which is so large it cuts out the important part.

Comment: Hello dessert, thank you for your help.  Being too new to this O.S. I will reformat the hard drive and start fresh.  Sorry to have been a pest but so many things pop up with errors I just didn't log them all, (or any), again thank you for your help.  Rod.